Vue Excel Editor
How to change the color of this validation message
<vue-excel-column field="phone" label="Contact" type="string" width="130px" :validate="validPhoneNum" />
methods: {
    validPhoneNum (content, oldContent, record, field) {
        if (content === '') return 'Mandatory field'
        if (!/^[0-9]{1}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{7}$/.test(content)) return 'Invalid Phone Number'
        return '' // return empty string if there is no error
    }
}

How to change the color of this validation message
